# C Program to Get Characters into Array and Reverse Order

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to create a C program that accepts a line of characters from the console, stores them in an array, reverses the order in the array, and displays the reversed string. I'm not allowed to use any library functions other than `getchar()` and `printf()`. My attempt is below. When I run the program and enter some text and press Enter, nothing happens. Can someone point out the fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100

main()
{
    char c;                     // the current character
    char my_strg[MAX_SIZE];     // character array
    int i;                      // the current index of the character array

    // Initialize my_strg to null zeros
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        my_strg[i] = '\0';
    }

    /* Place the characters of the input line into the array */
    i = 0;
    printf("\nEnter some text followed by Enter: ");
    while ( ((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (i < MAX_SIZE) )
    {
        my_strg[i] = c;
        i++;
    }

    /* Detect the end of the string */
    int end_of_string = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (my_strg[i] != '\0')
    {
        end_of_string++;
    }

    /* Reverse the string */
    int temp;
    int start = 0;
    int end = (end_of_string - 1);
    while (start < end)
    {
        temp = my_strg[start];   
        my_strg[start] = my_strg[end];
        my_strg[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }

    printf("%s\n", my_strg);

}
```

Comment: You are trying so solve three problems at once: reading a string into an array, reversing it, and displaying it. Tackle them one at a time, and don't try to combine them until they work perfectly.

Comment: Are you suggesting something like making each problem a separate function and testing each separately? We haven't got much into that yet but I'm sure that's a better approach.

Comment: You could do that, or you could write three separate *programs*, and test them separately. Believe me, it can save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Thank you -- I will try that approach. I can see now where doing different things at once can "clutter" the brain.

Comment: OT: Is should be `int main(void)` at least.

Comment: OT: Using an appropriate initialiser (`char my_strg[MAX_SIZE] = "";`) would make the initialisation-loop unnecessary:

Comment: @alk re: `int main(void)` Of course you're right, but perhaps not essential for me at this stage. re: initializer, thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like in this while loop:

```
while (my_strg[i] != '\0')
{
    end_of_string++;
}
```

you should increment `i`, otherwise if `my_strg[0]` is not equal to `'\0'`, that's an infinite loop.
I'd suggest putting a breakpoint and look what your code is doing.

Comment: You nailed it! I was actually playing around with _gdb_ before posting here but was having a hard time of it. I'm not working in an IDE as per our professor's requirement. Our professor said we'll be covering debugging later in the course (!), but would seem to be an important enough topic to cover right at the beginning -- at least the basics of it.

Comment: there actually simple ways to debug without properly debugging. For example you may use `printf("Before while loop\n");` and `printf("After while loop");` to have a clue of where the program is stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at your second while loop and ask yourself where my_string[i] is being incremented because to me it looks like it is always at zero...

Comment: Yes, you are correct as @peval27 also pointed out. Thank you.